# Downloading a ZIP file from a POST response in PHP

Tags: php, curl, post, php-curl

In Python I can write this code:

```
def func(url, configuration_username, configuration_pass):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        params = {
            'configuration_username': configuration_username,
            'configuration_pass': configuration_pass,
        }
        if response.status_code == 200:
            if 'Login error' not in response.text:
                print('OK: Login success')
                downloaded_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
                downloaded_zip.extractall()
            else:
                print('ERROR: Login error')
        else:
            print('ERROR: Received status code %d' % response.status_code)
```

Basically, there is a site login. When you enter your credentials and press Submit, it sends a POST request with the respective credentials. The response is a .ZIP file, but it sends the login page source too. In Python I was able to get this working because response.content had the ZIP file data in bytes, and response.text was the page source code. That way, I can check response.text for any errors from the webpage and then write the bytes from response.content to a ZIP and extract it. I want to rewrite this in PHP, but I do not want to receive the page source code too.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");

$configuration_username = "myusername";
$configuration_pass = "mypass";
$params = array(
    "configuration_username" => $configuration_username,
    "configuration_pass" => $configuration_pass
);
$server_url = "http://myurl.com";
$ch = curl_init($server_url);
$destination_file = "/var/www/html/filetest.zip";
$file_resource = fopen($destination_file, "w");
$curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_resource);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ((curl_errno($ch)) or (!$response)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
fclose($file_resource);

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

This code above writes the response bytes to a file, but the result is the ZIP bytes in addition to the page source code. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure you need this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);`?  From the docs - `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER TRUE to return the raw output when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used.` I think you don't need that flag on perhaps, as it is just returning the raw output. CURLOPT_FILE should be handling the binary transfer aspect.

Comment: @dgig Omitting BINARYTRANSFER seems to have to affect on the results so you are correct, however I still must devise a way to put only the ZIP data in the file.